# Some questions about sessions and cookies in PHP

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, authentication

I'm new to PHP, I've read a lot of tutorials about cookies and sessions but I don't understand some things clearly:

1. The session values are stored on the server, only the session id is stored in the users computer. Right?
2. Can I make a session that never expires, that is never deleted from the server and to save the session id in a cookie ? If yes than how ? (please provide me some code)
3. It`s not good to store data like passwords in cookies because cookies are not secure ? Right ?
4. It`s possible for a hacker to create a cookie with a session id of an another user ? Can a hacker guess the session id of a session or worst, the list with each session id ?
5. For a good login system (used for forums or websites where the user have some data) that can remember an user is better to use cookies, sessions or a combination of both with session id stored in cookies ?
6. Please provide me some code about how could I store the session id in a cookie and than how I can access a session if I know the session id

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see...

1. right
2. session that never expires ? Not quite a good idea :

   - your served would get filled with old, useless, sessions
   - Instead, you should store some data in a long-lasting cookie ; and use that cookie to re-create the session (auto-connecting the user, for example) when the user comes back later
3. cookies are not secure indeed : they are stored unencrypted, and go through the network unencrypted (unless you use HTTS).
4. If your *hacker* can get the session id of another user (by reading his cookies, typically), yes, he can access his session
5. I would use both : anyway, if using a session, you need a way to store its identifier.
6. storing the session id in a cookie ? PHP will do that for you, if configured properly ;-)

Comment: And what if I store a password in a cookie, but first I encrypt it:

Comment: That's not encryption, but hashing : you will not be able to get the password from that string ; but I suppose it's better than a clear-text password

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, PHP sessions are stored on the server.
2. You don't want to do that. It's a waste of disk space.
3. No, it's not good because cookies are stored unencrypted and in plaintext and you should never send a plaintext password back to the user.
4. If he knows the session id then he might be able to take over a session (tieing sessions to the user's IP helps against that). That's one of the resons why XSS is a dangerous thing.
5. Use a session and store the userid in it. There's no need to use a separate cookie if you already have the sessionid cookie.
6. Use [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/session-set-cookie-params) if you want to change the session cookie settings; e.g. to make it permanent.

Comment: Thanks but at the question 6 can you please give me some code, I don`t know what to do with that function... Can you write and example code in PHP ?

Comment: #2. For session that never expires, store the session data with user_id in database instead of server file system. Based on user_id you can retrieve the session data from database.